# Wait for fireEvent to finish extjs

Tags: extjs

I execute an event with fireEvent function, right after I execute another JS function. Is it possible to wait for fireEvent to finish, next function relies on fireEvent results.

```
panel.fireEvent('generate', obj);
setData();
```

I did not see any callback as parameter for fireEvent function, and I do not want to move or pass function inside a function wich I called using fireEvent.

Any ideas how could I wait for fireEvent to finish?

Comment: `fireEvent()` is synchronous, so unless you're doing something asynchronously in one of your listeners (like a network call for example), `setData()` won't get called until all of the listeners have finished. Though even then it's still getting called after they all finished, but it might make you think that it was called early

Comment: all stores are ready, and I just generate some elements and assign stores to them. probably because of afterrender ?
Problem is I have combobox, in fireEvent I generate it and it has afterrender where I assign store to it, but in setData I do not see this store.

Comment: can you show us the listener(s) that handle the 'generate' event you are firing?

Comment: oh, generate is very big, main idea is -  function generate combobox, it has afterrender where I assign store to it, but in setData I do not see this store. And output shows that setData trying to set data on empty combobox and after I see output from afterrender.

Comment: yes, problem is in afterrender, afterrender called after setData, which is understandable. But how could I trigger setData after afterrender? without moving setData inside?

Comment: Could you load the store first and put call back to generate the combobox inside the load?